# Remove an element to a state list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following variable on my state:

```
this.state = {

        playerList: {
            player: [
                {
                    playerAlias: [
                        {
                            name: null
                        }
                    ],
                    idPlayer: null,
                    playerName: null,
                    broadcastChannel: null,
                    clusterName: null
                }
            ]
        }

    }
```

what I wanted to do is to delete a certain item on that same list,and for that I wrote this method:

```
delete = (player) => {

    let listAux = this.state.playerList.player;

    let newList = [];

    listAux.map((playerAux) => {
        if (playerAux != player) {
            newList.push(playerAux)
        }
    })

    this.setState({
        playerList:newList
    })
}
```

I though that this would work but it does not, the following error appear when trying to iterate all my elements of my variable on the render method:

> Cannot read map of undefined, when trying to execute this for cycle this.state.playerList.player.map((player)

Comment: Thanks,my mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

1. `Array#map` is designed to create a new array with your modified values. `Array#forEach` is the appropriate method to use in this situation. But in this case you shouldn't be using either, because:
2. You're essentially reinventing `Array#filter`. Think of `filter` as doing the same operation with the exact opposite logic: Only keep values in my existing array if `playerAux != player`

```
const newList = this.state.playerList.player.filter((playerAux) => {
  return playerAux != player
})
this.setState({ playerList: newList })
```

EDIT: Keep in mind what `playerAux` is. It's actually the object itself:

```
{
  playerAlias: [
    {
      name: null
    }
  ],
  idPlayer: null,
  playerName: null,
  broadcastChannel: null,
  clusterName: null
}
```

I not 100% sure what you're trying to compare, but it's probably `playerName`, which would make it `playerAux.playerName != player`